# MySQL Update anniversary date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project and have trouble updating a date field (**YYYY-MM-DD**) using another date field (**YYYY-MM-DD**). I have searched and people use stored procedures and cursors to iterate with each result but I'm not sure what to do.

So I need to get the last anniversary date and update the field `registration_date` if `date` is greater than today's date `CURDATE()`.

*wp_wf_golf_res* is a table for reservations.

This is what I have:

```
 UPDATE wp_wf_golf_res 
 INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_wf_golf_res.user_id = wp_users.ID 
 SET wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date = *anniversaryDate* 
 WHERE wp_wf_golf_res.date > CURDATE();
```

Table 1: wp_users Columns: `ID (PK)`, `user_registered` Table2: wp_wf_golf_res Columns: `id (PK)`, `date`, `registration_date`.

*AnniversaryDate* should be updated into `registration_date` if `date` is greater than today. If `date` is less than today update `registration_date` with `user_registered` value.

`wp_users.user_registered` is the date the user registered. `wp_wf_golf_res.date` is the reservation date. `wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date` means the date a reservation was made, like a log. And *anniversarydate* is what needs to be calculated and updated in `wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date`.

Comment: Please share table structure (relevant columns) of the two tables concerned here.

Comment: What is **anniversaryDate**?

Comment: by 'get the last anniversary date' do you mean return in to the application?

Comment: anniversaryDate is the value I need to update. If `date`is '2012-01-20' anniversaryDate should be '2018-01-20'.

Comment: @SkoobGeneral you need to update `registration_date` or `anniversaryDate` ?

Comment: Table 1:  wp_users
Columns: ID (PK), user_registered

Table2: wp_wf_golf_res
Columns: id (PK), date, registration_date

*AnniversaryDate should be updated into `registration_date` if `date` is greater than today. If `date` is less than today update `registration_date` with `user_registered` value.*

Comment: Please **edit your request**, when you want to add information. Don't hide the information in comments. Please show the tables with all columns and their datatypes. Please also add semantic information so we understand better what you want to do (and why you want to do it): what does wp_wf_golf_res represent?

Comment: There are four dates mentioned: `date`, aniversarydate`, `registration_date`, `user_registered` and I must admit that I cannot really tell them apart. Can you please explain what each date stands for?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Thorsten. `wp_users.user_registered` is the date the user registered. The others represent reservations `wp_wf_golf_res.date` is the reservation date. `wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date` means the date a reservation was made, like a log. And anniversarydate is what needs to be calculated and updated in `wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date`.

Comment: This sounds queer. A reservation in table `wp_wf_golf_res` is made on the day `registration_date` for the day `date`. Now you want to manipulate the `registration_date` of all records, so to make it seem the reservations were made at completely different days. (Why?) If the reservation is made for a past date you want to pretend the reservation was made on the day the user was registered. If the reservation was made for a future date, you want to pretend the reservation was made on the user's last aniversary date. Yes?

Comment: Yes, correct.

I know it sounds stupid to manipulate the log a reservation was made, but it's necessary. There are some past reservations and future reservations in the table. All this was messed up because there was no log on each reservation and now they want to put a limit of reservations every year. In order to know who has reached the limit or not, reservations that are greater than today in the table logs need to have the last *annivesarydate*. Only need this fix, new reservations will have normal log and be counted in the user limit per year.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you need an conditional update so instead of where you can use case when but due to lack of table structure it's difficult to give your desired answer

```
 UPDATE wp_wf_golf_res INNER JOIN wp_users ON 
 wp_wf_golf_res.user_id = wp_users.ID 
 SET wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date = case when wp_wf_golf_res.date > CURDATE() 
 then date(concat(concat(year(now()),'-'),DATE_FORMAT(wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date, "%m-%d"))) when wp_wf_golf_res.date < CURDATE() then user_registered end
```

Comment: Great to use case to avoid two queries, now just the tough part is missing. Get the Anniversary date, if `registration_date` is = '2012-01-20' Anniversary date should be = '2018-01-20'.

Comment: I've modified the answer you can check now

Comment: Thanks in advance, what I meant was the *last anniversary date* which means not just the anniversary.  '2012-01-20' -> '2018-01-20' instead of '2013-01-20'.

Comment: Correct. If I compare the `registration_date` and today's date should be equal or less than 1 year.

Comment: modified my answer, you can check now

Comment: select date(concat(concat(year(now()),'-'),DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-15', "%m-%d")))  check it -- it returns a date, so if your wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date column is in proper date then it'll definitely show result

Comment: There seems to be a problem, when I run the code future reservations appear "2018-00-00".

Comment: I will check it :D

Comment: `UPDATE wp_wf_golf_res INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_wf_golf_res.user_id = wp_users.ID SET wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date = CASE WHEN wp_wf_golf_res.date >= CURDATE() THEN date(concat(concat(year(now()),'-'),DATE_FORMAT(wp_users.user_registered, '%m-%d'))) WHEN wp_wf_golf_res.date < CURDATE() THEN user_registered END`
**That was it! Many Thanks :D**

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you're using Innodb since transactions are required.

```
BEGIN;

SELECT {other fields}, DATE_ADD(wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS anniversaryDate
FROM wp_wf_golf_res 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_wf_golf_res.user_id = wp_users.ID 
WHERE wp_wf_golf_res.date > CURDATE()
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE wp_wf_golf_res 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_wf_golf_res.user_id = wp_users.ID 
SET wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date = DATE_ADD(wp_wf_golf_res.registration_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I'm looking for the last anniversary, means if `user_registered` is '2012-01-20' *last anniversary* should be '2018-01-20'.

Answer (score 0):

First we must answer **this question**: when was a user's last aniversary?

**The answer to this question is:** Today is September 3, 2018. So if a user's registration day was before September 3, the aniversary was this year (e.g. August 12, 2018). If the user's registration day was after September 3, the aniversary was last year (e.g. November 1, 2017).

(Well, you'll want to include today in one of the two ranges, of course; decide which.)

We can compare month and day as strings (format = two digits for month, two digits for day):

```
'0812' < '0903' < '1101'
```

The complete update statement:

```
UPDATE wp_wf_golf_res r
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON r.user_id = u.id 
SET r.registration_date = 
  CASE
    WHEN r.date < current_date THEN
      u.user_registered;
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(current_date, '%m%d') THEN 
      r.registration_date + INTERVAL YEAR(current_date) - YEAR(r.registration_date) YEAR
    ELSE
      r.registration_date + INTERVAL YEAR(current_date) - YEAR(r.registration_date) - 1 YEAR
    END
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D